# I have a very strange crash. Please see my stack trace

Tags: ios, memory-management, crash

My class DownloadViewControl.

```
@interface DownloadViewControl : UIViewController
{
 IBOutlet UIProgressView *progress;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *chapterLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *timeLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
```

// *.m file

```
- (void)dealloc {
[chapterLabel release];
[timeLabel release];
[button release];

[progress release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

I have a very strange crash. Please see my stack trace.

[image]

Comment: It would help immensely to actually know the text of the error message....

Comment: Then I greatly concur with the below answer.  EXC_BAD_ACCESS is a result of too many release calls 90% of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without the specific error message, but here's my guess:

IBOutlets are by convention not retained, since a subview of your view is already retained by its superview. When you're releasing the `progress` control it goes away without getting removed from its superview, and then when you call `super` it releases your view hierarchy, including the `progress` control which is already gone.

So, you probably don't want `[progress release]` in there.